# Upload Image to external image service

Tags: meteor

My meteor application need to be enriched with an image upload functionality. Since many free image upload services exist, I thought the best way of doing it would be by using an existing image upload service. My choice fell on [imgur](https://imgur.com/). I guess I somehow have to use [imgur's image upload API](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image), but this looks completely alien to me.

**Here are my questions:**

1. Is imgur appropriate for what I want? Do you know a better or simpler solution?
2. How do I upload an image to imgur from my meteor application?

You can assume that the image file comes from an html file input tag. Later on, when the mobile app catches up, the image should come from the camera, but let's just tackle one difficulty at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FSCollection](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) will be a great option here, you can use grids (to store images on the db) or use fs(to store in certain path)

For better explanation i made this tinny demo here is the [DEMO](http://demo.fscollection.meteor.com) and the [code](https://github.com/Ethaan/simple-uploadFS)

Also i made this example using the progress bar, again here is the link to the [DEMO](http://padondefile.meteor.com) and [Source Code](https://github.com/Ethaan/padonde-file-upload)

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution would be to just store images in MongoDB or your filesystem using CollectionFS along with `cfs:filesystem` for your local file system or `cfs:gridfs` for MongoDB. The [docs](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) are clear and simple enough to get you up and running quickly.

If you wanted to use imgur, you'd need to be able to POST data and understand what you're doing. CollectionFS has a [methods package](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-http-methods) which adds an HTTP POST method to Meteor, but honestly I think that'll just complicate things for you at this point. Keep it local for now.